# In what context/scenarios can I use the phrase 'in that'?

Tags: phrases

What is actually the use of the phrase 'in that'?

For instance,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgQVj4iMm8Y&t=135s

2:15 in this video.

> Russel Crowe is delightfully paradoxical **in that** he is a huge d**k with a small p***s.

---

P.S. Sorry for the bad language in the video. But, I couldn't find any better example.

Comment: Please write the full sentence where "in that" is used in the linked video. Also, have you done enough research to find what "in that" could mean? http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/in%20that

Comment: You really couldn't find any better example than that? What about just looking [in a dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in-that), where you'll find things like *The new system is better **in that** it provides faster access to the Internet.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you have the liberty to edit the question-body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***in that*** construction, in the context you mean, is generally (and in my view properly) used to link two declarative statements, each in a form that comprises a *term* in the syllogistic sense, where it refers to "each of the two concepts being compared or related in a proposition" (TFDO).

So you can say

> A **in that** B.

where B is an illumination or explanation of A. Thus we can have

> Abraham Lincoln was a statesman in that he acted in the best interests of his country.

or, a more complex example,

> *Hamlet* is a religious drama in that it expresses the consequences of an unchecked evil that winds up polluting the main character and almost everything around him.

Comment: I'm not sure *Socrates is mortal, **in that** he is a man* really does it for me. I'd normally only expect the format *A **in that** B* to be used where ***A*** wouldn't *normally*  be recognised as an obvious (or even, *likely*) true statement. That's to say, your Hamlet example seems completely natural to me (because we *don't* axiomatically categorise *Hamlet* as a religious drama; ***A*** is only really a "natural" classification *when considered from the **B** perspective*). But the Lincoln one doesn't have much of an *"in light of **B**"* element.

Comment: @Fumble: Any construction can be obtuse or perspicacious. I was concentrating on demonstrating mechanics, not brilliance.

Comment: I think maybe my understanding of how ***in that*** is properly used might be somewhat flawed, in that I even disagree with the *dictionary*. I just found ***in that*** definition: 33 *because; inasmuch as,* with example [In that you won't have time for supper, let me give you something now.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in--that), which I find just "weird".